# How to loop over a list of monadic values?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a list of `3` values: `es = [MyMonad 33, MyMonad 55, MyMonad 88]`. Then I would perform

```
do v1 <- funcReturningMyMonad (es !! 0)
   v2 <- funcReturningMyMonad (es !! 1)
   v3 <- funcReturningMyMonad (es !! 2)
   funcTakingListOfInts [v1,v2,v3]
```

My problem is that I would like to somehow achieve this behavior for a list of arbitrary length `n`. In the above case `n` was `3`. I thought about calling `(>>=)` sequentially through the list but it doesn't add up. How would you achieve this behavior?

Function types:

```hs
funcReturningMyMonad :: MyMonad Int -> MyMonad Int
funcTakingListOfInts :: [Int] -> MyMonad Int
```

Comment: I renamed your question, please let me know, if you are okay with the renaming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since

```
funcReturningMyMonad :: MyMonad Int -> MyMonad Int
```

we can use

```
mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

for the first part, which in our case will be

```
 (MyMonad Int -> MyMonad Int) -> [MyMonad Int] -> MyMonad [Int]
```

then we can use the bind operator for applying `funcTakingListOfInts` so you'd end up with:

```
(mapM funcReturningMyMonad es) >>= funcTakingListOfInts
```

Comment: Uhh, I think this is it!! But I am trying to understand it rn - can you tell me how can `mapM` accept `funcReturningMyMonad` when the expected type is `(a -> m b)` and the type of `funcReturningMyMonad` is `m b -> m b` -- I mean `funcReturningMyMonad` returns the same monadic type as it takes as argument?

Comment: Well `a` is a type variable that can be *any* type, so there is no problem in it being the same type as `m b`.  Or an easier example: `fst :: (a, b) -> a`. This can still be applied to `(1, 2) :: (Int, Int)` with `a == b`, there is no need for them to be different.

Comment: Makes sense of course, thanks! I appreciate your help!